# rails converting an include query that returns nil into scope lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The following query is returning nil  in some instances

```
 scope :claim_one, where(" location_id IS NULL OR start_time IS NULL OR archived IS NULL " ).includes(:instructor_assignments).where('instructor_assignments.user_id IS NULL')
```

I would like to convert the query into a lambda function that takes care of the nil returned by the query  as follows ;

```
scope :claim, (lambda  do  |claim| where(" location_id IS NULL OR start_time IS NULL OR archived IS NULL ").includes(:instructor_assignments).where('instructor_assignments.user_id IS NULL', claim ) unless claim.nil? end )
```

The latter does not work as I don't think it has the correct rails syntax

Thank you

Comment: Howdy.  Sorry, what do you mean by "take care of the nil"?  Do you want to avoid a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error, or return a different value when the query returns no results?

Comment: One more thing: is 'claim' a parameter which you want to pass to the query, or do you want to bind it to the result of your query?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand (see comment above), but I hope this will help.  I think that the results from your code will be an ActiveRecord::Relation with no records in it rather than nil.  I am assuming "claim" is a parameter you want to pass in.  If that is the case, you can add it as below.

The preferred way to deal with lambda scopes is much nicer now; just use a class method:

```
def self.claim_one(claim)
  return [whatever you want] unless claim
  where(" location_id IS NULL OR start_time IS NULL OR archived IS NULL " ).
    includes(:instructor_assignments).
    where('instructor_assignments.user_id IS NULL')
end
```

I would suggest the following though to make your scopes easier to use separately, easier to understand and test, and just darn purty:

```
def self.incomlete()
  where(" location_id IS NULL OR start_time IS NULL OR archived IS NULL " )
end

def self.without_instructor()
  includes(:instructor_assignments).where('instructor_assignments.user_id IS NULL')
end
```

To call this, I would use something like:

```
result = YourModel.incomplete.without_instructor
if result.empty?
  # do yo funky "ain't got no records dance"
else
  # record jackpot!  
end
```

Did that answer your question?

Comment: You might also need to follow the scope definition in `def self.claim_one(claim)` with `references(:instructor_assignments)` -- see also http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Answer (score 0):

Very well, I should have stated things in a much better way

I am using the CanCan gem from [Ryan Bates CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

In my view I have the following code :

```
  <% if can? :claim, @workshop %>
  <%= link_to claim_workshop_path(@workshop), :method =>  :post , :class => "mybtn btn-mini claim-workshop-button"  do %>
    <%= t(:Claim) %>
    <%= content_tag(:i, "", :class => "icon-thumbs-up").html_safe %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to be able to use te :claim ability from [Ryan Bates CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)
For that I need a scope to be able to use that query, as described in the link above. But sometimes the query return no results -- or nil --.

In my ability.rb file I have the following code that uses the scope

```
f user.role == "admin" || user.role  = "scheduler"
     can :manage, :all
     can :claim , Workshop.claim do |workshop_instance|
       # workshop_instance.can_claim?
        workshop_instance.instructor_assignments.nil?
     end
   else
     can :read, :all
   end
```

In the class User I defined the scope need it to obtain my result

```
 scope :claim, where(" location_id IS NOT NULL OR start_time IS NOT NULL  " ).includes(:instructor_assignments).where('instructor_assignments.user_id IS NOT NULL')
```